# django models and OOP design

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models

I wrote a quest system for an online game. My quests are serialized into `json objects` for a JavaScript client that fetches those quests then from a REST backend (I use django RestFramework)

Now I'm wondering on which `class` or `django model` I should put the "behaviour" that belongs to the data.

I stored the data that belongs to a quest in several separate models:
A `model QuestHistory`: with `models.Fields` like `Boolean completed`, and `Datetime started` where I put the information belonging to a specific user (it also as a field user).

Then I have a `model QuestTemplate` : The part that is always the same, fields like `quest_title` and  `quest_description`

I also have a `model Rewards` and `model Task and TaskHistory` that are linked to a quest with a `foreign Key field`.

To combine this information back to quest I created a pure python `class Quest(object):` and defined methods on this class like `check_quest_completion`. This class is the then later serialized. The Problem with this approach is that It becomes quite verbose, for example when I instantiate this class or when I define the Serializer.

Is there a python or django "shortcut" to put all fields of a `django model` into another class (my Quest class here), something similar to the `dict.update` method maybe?

Or should I try to put the methods on the `models` instead and get rid of the `Quest class`?

I have some other places in my game that look very similar to the quest system for example the inventory system so I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the methods of the Quest class on the model itself and get rid of the Quest class.

Comment: If I want to get the quests as "a whole", I think I still need a single class for the quests in order to use it together with the Serializer class. Do you have a sugestion where you would for example put a method that checks whether the user has completed all the tasks that belongs to this quest?

Comment: I think this should be a query for all QuestHistory objects filtered on the "user" and "completed" fields.