# Django REST framework serializing model combinations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm programming an online game with a JavaScript client and I use `Django REST framework` for the backend. I have written a quest system for it.

My quests objects are dynamically created from a `django model QuestTemplate` which stores information like the Quest desription and the titel (the part that is the same for every user); and another `model QuestHistory`  where I put the information about the state of quest for a certain user: so it has fields like `user` and `completed`. They also have some nested objects: Tasks and, Rewards which are created in a similar way to the the Quest objects.

I added a pure python class Quest that combines all the fields of those models, and then I wrote a Serializer for this class. The drawback is that I have to define all the fields again in the `QuestSerializer`

I have seen that for the `ModelSerializer` you can use a `inner class Meta` where you specifiy the model and . Is there also a way to do this with a normal python class instead of a model (with my Quest class).
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-nested-serialization

Or:

Is it possible to specify more than one model in this inner class, so that it takes fields from my  `model QuestTemplate` and some other fields from my `model QuestHistory`?

(I'm also not sure about whether this structure makes sense and asked about it here: [django models and OOP design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898132/django-models-and-oop-design) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class Meta of the ModelSerializer you can specify only one Model as far as I know. However there are possibilities to add custom fields to the serializer. In your case you could maybe try with:

```
custom_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('some_method_in_your_serializer')
```

You should add the method to your serializer like this:

```
def some_method_in_your_serializer(self, obj):
    # here comes your logic to get fields from other models, probably some query
    return some_value # this is the value that comes into your custom_field
```

And add the custom_field to fields in the class Meta:

```
class Meta:
    fields = ('custom_field', 'all_other_fields_you_need')
```

Take a look in the documentation about SerializerMethodField for deeper understanding.